# Printing special characters in console (C++/C#/SWIG)

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am attempting to port a library over from C++ to C# with SWIG. I was able to successfully generate the interface and got the basic progress bar working. Now the only problem is getting the other progress bars to work.The code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/gregyjames/csharp-tqdm/blob/master/tqdm.h), includes special characters used in the "progress" animation of the other bars. However, I have no idea to print these characters in the console window.

I tried setting `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8` in my C# tester project but it didn't help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please put relevant code into your question. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Were the special characters Unicode? ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly,  you will probably need to change the font in the console itself.

More so, if the console shows question marks `?`  you will most likely need to set the console font to a *TrueType* font (e.g. *Consolas* or *Lucida Console*). The console tries to convert everything into the OEM character set, characters that cannot be converted become question marks. I suggest playing around in there

Comment: I tried changing the font to Lucida Console. Now the [?] characters are replaced with empty bracket characters []. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @gregyjames reduce the complexity, and just try to print a the Unicode character you need in a simple console app with the `OutPutEncoding` set to utf8, try diffrent fonts until you can get it to work, you will need a font that understands the character